# What is the Content-Type for mp3 files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, audio, mp3, content-type

I am trying to code a web server, using the node.js 'http' module. Can anyone tell me what the 'Content-Type' header value is for mp3/audio files is? For example:

```
response.writeHead(200, "OK", {"Content-Type": "audio/mp3"});
```

I hope I explained myself well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `audio/mpeg`.

I usually search for `mime types` to find out what should be sent as the `Content-Type` header for files.

--UPDATE--

Reading a bit more about Mime-Types, it is infact 'mime-type' that we send as Content-Type header for files.